# Make an event fire when reply from HTML form-submit is done

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML5 form that I use to submit a query:

```
<form action="/get_my_download/" method="get">
    ...
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

I know I can fire an event before submitting the form using `onsubmit="my_pre_submit_function()"`, but is there a way to fire an event **after** the form has been submitted and the reply has been received? It's worth noting that the response to this form is a file download, and submitting the form with AJAX is out of the question since Javascript can't touch the file system. How can I be notified that the response is complete?

Comment: *submitting the form with AJAX is out of the question since Javascript can't touch the file system.* - Using AJAX would call your server - which does have access to the file system. AJAX is going to be needed else your page will just redirect once the submit is done.

Answer (score 0):

**The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) only list two `form` events : `submit` and `reset`.**

---

Thus, you need a wrapper function that submits the form and then performs some action. If `AJAX is 'out of the question" I think you're out of luck, bud.

Why exactly can't you use AJAX? As [tymeJV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686485/tymejv) mentioned, **AJAX is just performing a call to the server; it doesn't grant access to the file system**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type button instead of submit and do you own submission using xhr. This will give you more control...

Comment: Can you submit `xhr` without using JavaScript?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why would you want it to be done without javascript? Don't you have access to javascript?

Comment: As per OP: "Javascript can't touch the file system" (don't ask me why :/) .

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote that Ajax is out of the question although I don't understand what you think you can achieve using submit and not through button...

Comment: I didn't write it, OP wrote it: *"Submitting the form with AJAX is out of the question..."* I think the real question here is if OP can submit a form and perform an operation **at all** without using JavaScript. :/